# Can not connect remotly with X11 and SSH? err: Can't open display, What's wrong?

Tags: ssh, x11

$ xterm works on the client computer

In the client I have :

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

in the config file in the server /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
```

trying to connect to the remote server:

```
$ssh -X user@host

@server01:/etc/ssh$ xterm &
[1] 4237
@server01:/etc/ssh$ xterm Xt error: Can't open display:
xterm: DISPLAY is not set
^C
[1]+ Exit 1 xterm
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `-Y` instead of `-X`?

Answer (score 1):

X forwarding can be disabled on the server side. If the server is running OpenSSH, `X11Fowarding` must be explicitly set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Unfortunately, if the option isn't set, there's nothing you can do other than running your own server or setting up a port forwarding manually with `-R` (if you do that, you don't benefit from automatic port allocation or xauth cookie handling).

Comment: I think is an authorization problem can you explain further the xauth cookie handling and how should it be set up properly in ubuntu 11.04.  Thanks.

Comment: @mancora When ssh does X11 forwarding, it takes care of the xauth cookies. Doing it manually is possible, just annoying. For a more general presentation of X cookies, read [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/ssh-display-variable/10126#10126).

Comment: The problem is that I have everything properly configure in the server. I have the client and it can do a ssh -X user@server and open a ssh session. But this gives me can "can not open display" when I try to run xterm. From what I think it is a problem with Authorization something had been fault with the cookies I think.

Comment: @mancora What does `echo $DISPLAY` show in the ssh session?

Answer (score 0):

In some [posts](http://www.snowfrog.net/2011/11/06/ssh-display-is-not-set-failed-to-allocate-internet-domain-x11-display-socket/), I read : "add `AddressFamily inet` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`", but don't work for my.

My problem was, I don't have `lo` interface. I solved added to `/etc/network/interfaces` file this lines

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```